# Scrapy random number in single start_url

Tags: python, random, scrapy

I have one start URL and only want to crawl one page, however I want to randomly choose that page by entering a random number between 1 and 50 in the start_url:

```
start_urls = ["http://www.modcloth.com/shop/bedding?sorting=loved&page=1"]
```

where page= Random Number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the standard [`random.randint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) library function.

```
from random import randint

start_urls = ["http://www.modcloth.com/shop/bedding?sorting=loved"
              "&page={0}".format(randint(1,50))]
```